# glGetAttribLocation returns -1 when retrieving existing shader attribute

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, vertex-shader

I'm trying to pass in attributes to my vertex shader but for some reason it keeps giving me a -1 on the 3rd attribute location I'm asking openGl to retrieve via glGetAttribLocation(). Currently it keeps giving me a -1 for the texCoord attribute and if I switch the texAttrib and colAttrib around (switching the lines in code) it gives me a -1 on the color property instead of the texture and I have no idea why? Since a -1 is being passed to glVertexAttribPointer I get the 1281 OpenGL error: GL_INVALID_VALUE.

My vertex shader:

```
#version 150

in vec3 position;
in vec3 color;
in vec2 texcoord;

out vec3 Color;
out vec2 Texcoord;

void main()
{
    Color = color;
    Texcoord = texcoord;
    gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0);
}
```

OpenGL code:

```
basicShader.Use();

// Buffers and shaders
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);

glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
// Make it active vbo
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);

// Build basic triangle
float vertices[] = {
    // position         // color          // textures
    -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // Top-left
     0.5f,  0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // Top-right
     0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // Bottom-right
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f// Bottom-left
};
GLuint elements[] = {
    0, 1, 2,
    2, 3, 0
};

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

GLint posAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(basicShader.shaderProgram, "position");
glEnableVertexAttribArray(posAttrib); // Enable attribute first before specifiying attributes
glVertexAttribPointer(posAttrib, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), 0); // 6 float sizes is every new vertex

GLint colAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(basicShader.shaderProgram, "color");
glEnableVertexAttribArray(colAttrib);
glVertexAttribPointer(colAttrib, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float))); // same for color + offset

GLint texAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(basicShader.shaderProgram, "texcoord"); // Returns -1
glEnableVertexAttribArray(texAttrib);
glVertexAttribPointer(texAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(6 * sizeof(float))); // 6 offset from beginning

[..]
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You should stop using `glGetAttribLocation`. [*Assign* each attribute a location](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Shader#Inputs), either with `glBindAttribLocation` before linking the program or with explicit attribute locations, if that's available to you.

That way, if the compiler optimizes an attribute away (which is what's happening here; your fragment shader probably doesn't use one of the interpolated values), you won't care. You'll set up your arrays as normal, using a standard convention for attribute indices. Plus, you won't have to keep asking what an attribute location is every time you want to render with a different program; you *know* what location it is because you assigned it.

If you can't/won't, then there's nothing you can do. The compiler will optimize away attributes if you're not actually using them. The only thing you can do is detect that it returns -1 and not set up the array for that attribute.

Comment: I see. Got that from a tutorial (maybe they introduced it like that to keep things simple or something?), the variable was indeed optmized by the compiler and using glBindAttribLocation solves the problem. Thanks! :)

Comment: If someone assign only using glBindAttribLocation it will not work on Radeon cards. You will need to assign directly using the layout on the input declaration in the GLSL code. Recently, I lost a lot of time trying to figure out why a code was working on a nVidia and wasn't on a Radeon card. It seems AMD guys kinda ignored glBindAttribLocation.

Comment: Just to note on an Nvidia card, My driver ignored both glBindAttribLocation and the explicit location given in GLSL. Only when I actually ensured usage of the vertex attrib would glGetAttribLocation not return -1.

Comment: @Balk: That's normal. If you don't use an attribute, the compiler is free to throw it away.